# switching .carousel height and width depening on landscape or portrait photo

Tags: html, css, carousel

I use the code below to fit my landscape(4:3) photo's in a carousel. But I would like to change the width and height of the .carousel depending on the photo(landscape or portrait). How can I do that?

```
html {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

body {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
}

.carousel {
 /* the percentages below are for a 4:3 landscape photo(1600x1200) */
 height: 60%;
 width: 70%;
}
```

/* I need to set height : 70%; and width: 60% for portrait */

Should I add an class to the carousel-item to indicate that it's a landscape or portrait photo?

Comment: Are you asking about changing the height and width based on the image being landscape or portrait, or the screen orientation of a mobile device?

Comment: On the image being landscape or portrait.

Answer (score 1):

Create one class for portrait and one for landscape. When the image loads or when you get the image size then determine if it is portrait or landscape and then add the appropriate class to the image or carousel container.

```js
// list of images - as requested you can put this list in a separate js file 
// make sure it is before the other code below
var imagesArray = ["https://lorempixel.com/300/500/animals/1", "https://lorempixel.com/300/500/animals/2", "https://lorempixel.com/500/300/animals/1","https://lorempixel.com/500/300/animals/2","https://lorempixel.com/500/300/city/1","https://lorempixel.com/300/500/city/2"];


// when the user clicks the random button 
// we get a random image from our list of URLS
// and then set that as the source of the image
function displayImage(direction, isURL) {
  var image = document.getElementById("myImage");
  var label = document.getElementById("loadingLabel");
  var list = imagesArray.slice(); //make a copy
  var currentURL = image.src;
  var currentIndex;
  var index = 0;
  var numberOfImages = list.length;
  
  if (isURL==true) {
    currentURL = direction;
  }
  
  currentIndex = list.indexOf(currentURL);
  
  if (direction=="next") {
    index = currentIndex>=list.length-1 ? 0 : currentIndex+1;
  }
  else if (direction=="previous") {
    index = currentIndex<=0 ? list.length-1 : currentIndex-1;
  }
  else if (direction=="random") {
    list.splice(currentIndex,1);
    index = Math.floor(Math.random()*list.length);
  }
  else if (direction=="start") {
    index = 0;
  }
  else if (direction=="end") {
    index = list.length-1;
  }
  else if (isURL) {
    if (currentIndex==-1) {
      console.log("Image not found in images array. Check the URL");
      return;
    }
    
    index = currentIndex;
  }
  else {
      console.log("Direction not specified");
  }
  
  image.src = list[index];
  label.innerHTML = "Loading " + list[index] + "...";
  label.title = list[index];
  updateNavigationLabel();
}

// this handles when the image has finished loading
// we check if the image is portrait or landscape
// if it is landscape we set the landscape class
// if it is portrait we set the portrait class
function imageLoadHandler(event) {
  var image = document.getElementById("myImage");
  var carousel = document.getElementById("myCarousel");
  var label = document.getElementById("loadingLabel");
  var width = image.naturalWidth;
  var height = image.naturalHeight;
  var isPortrait = width<height;
  var isSquare = width==height;
  
  carousel.classList.remove("portrait");
  carousel.classList.remove("landscape");
  
  var caption = width + "x" + height;

  if (isPortrait) {
    caption = "Portrait (" + caption + ")";
    carousel.classList.add("portrait");
  }
  else if (isPortrait==false) {
    caption = "Landscape (" + caption + ")";
    carousel.classList.add("landscape");
  }
   
  image.caption = caption;
  
  label.innerHTML = caption;
  updateNavigationLabel();
}


function updateNavigationLabel() {
  var image = document.getElementById("myImage");
  var label = document.getElementById("navigationLabel");
  var list = imagesArray.slice(); //make a copy
  var numberOfImages = list.length;
  var currentURL = image.src;
  currentIndex = list.indexOf(currentURL);
  label.innerHTML = currentIndex+1 +" of " + numberOfImages;
}


window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var element = document.getElementById("myImage");
  var button = document.getElementById("button");
  var carousel = document.getElementById("myCarousel");
  
  // listen for when an image loads
  element.addEventListener("load", imageLoadHandler);
  // listen for when the user clicks on the random button
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    displayImage('random')
  });

  // Options - load an image when the page loads
  
  // displayImage("start"); // use to load the first image
  // displayImage("end"); // use to load the last image
  // displayImage("random"); // use to load a random image
  // displayImage("specified", "https://lorempixel.com/300/500/animals/2"); // use to load an image in the images array

  displayImage("https://lorempixel.com/300/500/animals/2", true);

});
```

```css
.landscape {
  height: 60%;
  width: 70%;
  outline:2px solid blue;
}

.portrait {
  height: 70%;
  width: 60%;
  outline:2px solid purple;
}

#myCarousel {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

#myImage {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  outline: 1px dashed red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

#button {
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  top: 50px;
}

#loadingLabel {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#navigationLabel {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

#navigation {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!-- optionally set images in separate file. order before the main javascript --> 
<script src="myimages.js"></script>

<div id="myCarousel" class="landscape">
    <img id="myImage">
<label id="loadingLabel"></label>
</div>

<button id="button">random</button>

<div id="navigation">
  <button id="prev" onclick="displayImage('previous')">prev</button>
  <label id="navigationLabel"></label>
  <button id="next" onclick="displayImage('next')">next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I think that I understand where you are going but I do high understand your code.<br> What do the different function do and where should I add new pictures(I think at the list of the refresh...

Comment: I've updated the answer to fix an issue with landscape. It also has more comments.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the explantion.

I've got some additional questions 
Why doesn't he seem to work when I load hem alone (lodysreizen.nl/foto2.html) but does he work when I load him in a index page( lodysreizen.nl foto's 2 button).

Could you make a previos and next butten instead of a random? They should be places under the picture

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work on your site. You're links don't work. You would have to post your code here. You can see previous and next buttons.

Comment: Hi, I implemented your newest version but he only loads the first and the last picture. The index at the bottum of the page doens't wordt either.

I'm not sure what's wrong.
https://lodysreizen.nl/foto2.html the actual page and www.lodysreizen.nl press foito's 2 button for the load page in my overall website.

Comment: There is something wrong in what I do with the photo index. When I use your pictures it works fine, when I use mine it doens't. I think the only difference is de size of the picures (which I changed tot max 130 kb). Do they need to be even smaller for this all to work properly?

Comment: @Lody Have you used the Web Developer tools? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools. Most browsers come with tools that you can use to see what errors are occurring. It looks like the path to the images you use are incorrect.

Comment: it's a bit wierd. The location of my photos is in de map 'fotos'. So I thought that the 'fotos/1.jpg' should do the trick.(I also tried '/fotos/1.jpg'. Obviously it doesn't. I put the whole url (https://lodysreizen.nl/fotos/1.jpg) now at location in de ImagesArray and now it works. Thanks. I've got 2 small questions. 1) When I load the page he doesn't start with a photo. Just when I press a button the first photo comes up. How can I make it so the he starts with the photo I prefer and the goed to the next or the previous photo depending the button you press.

Comment: 2) I go on holiday and while traveling will add new photo's. Is it possible to make a separeted file in which all the photo names are places that I want to load into the imagesArray? This to protect the sourcecode of the html page.

Comment: @Lody You can specify the first image to load by placing it first in the images array. You can also use displayImage("specified", url);. If it is not working check start over with the example code and make sure that works and no errors in the console. Then add your own code back in.

Comment: @Lody I would create a separate question on loading in a separate file but you can create a new javascript file and use <script src="myimages.js"></script>. Then in that file have the `var imagesArray`.

Comment: pd, I didn't use that tool but at my work some collegas of mine do. I will ask them for some help how to use it.

Comment: @ 1.21 gigawatts thnx, gona try it out later this evening

Comment: Your script was trying to find the image before it was created so you would need to move the script block to the end of the page (after the image was declared) or add an event handler for the `DOMContentLoaded` event. That event signifies the document is ready (the image has been created). I've added an event handler for that.

Comment: @ 1.21 gigawatts, I've tried the new code but there still isn't a photo after I load te page. I use the "displayImage("start");" and changed the start index to 5 as a test. 

See : https://lodysreizen.nl/foto2.html